# Purely HTML/CSS solution to resizing content in javascript

Tags: html, css

Please, observe the following jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/DaYCa/14/:
[image]

The content is fit exactly between the header and the footer. This property of the layout is preserved if we add more items to the header (notice the scroll bar):
[image]
And now scrolling it:
[image]
We can add more items to the content:
[image]
And scroll down:
[image]
The scroll bar disappears once we resize the window:
[image]
Or reduce the content DOM tree:
[image]
Or reduce the header DOM tree:
[image]

This behavior is enforced in code. I was wondering whether there are HTML/CSS tricks that achieve the same effect in a purely declarative manner.

Here is the javascript code (to keep SO happy):

```
YUI().use('node', 'event-valuechange', function(Y){
    var headerNode = Y.one('.header');
    var footerNode = Y.one('.footer');
    var contentNode = Y.one('.content');
    var containerNode = Y.one('.container');

    function set(n, node){
        var i, content = [];

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
            content.push('<div>'+i+'</div>');
        }
        node.set('innerHTML', content.join(''));
    }
    function restyleContent(){
       var hh, fh, ch, bw;
        hh = headerNode.getDOMNode().getBoundingClientRect().height;
        fh = footerNode.getDOMNode().getBoundingClientRect().height;
        ch = containerNode.getDOMNode().getBoundingClientRect().height;
        bw = Number(contentNode.getComputedStyle('borderWidth').slice(0, -2));
        contentNode.setStyle('height', (ch - hh - fh - bw * 2) + 'px');
    }

    Y.one('win').on('resize', restyleContent);
    Y.one('#newContent').on('valuechange', function (e) {
        set(Number(e.newVal), contentNode);
    });
    Y.one('#newHeader').on('valuechange', function (e) {
        set(Number(e.newVal), headerNode);
        restyleContent();
    });

    set(Number(Y.one('#newContent').get('value')), contentNode);
    set(Number(Y.one('#newHeader').get('value')), headerNode);
    restyleContent();
});
```

​**EDIT**

I would like to relax the constraints a bit. Let us suppose the height of the header is known and cannot be changed. So, both the header and the footer have fixed constant heights known beforehand.

Comment: Can your header and footer be in fixed height?

Comment: The footer can, but the header cannot. This is why the jsFiddle allows to change it.

Comment: But if you give a solution that works with the fixed header I will credit it anyway, since I do not know to do it too.

Answer (score 2):

If fixed height is acceptable, you can use `position:fixed` and `padding`/`margin` to archive this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DaYCa/16/

essential part:

```css
.container {position:relative;padding:20px 0px 24px} /*dimension base on Chrome*/
.header {position:fixed;top:0px}
.footer {position:fixed;bottom:0px}
```

But I doubt if this is actually acceptable. Given that in your demo, JS is unavoidable anyway, I think this may help:

http://jsfiddle.net/DaYCa/17/

Very similar to the "pure" CSS solution, just added a simple JS to determine the size of header and footer (so to modify the `padding` part of `.container`).

Please be noted that I don't know YUI, so I made no-library demos.

Comment: jQuery will do too, I understand jQuery.

Comment: I wonder what are the advantages of using `fixed` over what I did, if JS is needed anyway?

Comment: @mark I have to admit there's no significant advantage. One _slightly_ advantage would be no need to calculate heights in JS (`ch-hh-fh-bw*2`): browser has taken care of that. So a more "CSS-driven" solution.